# After the substitution $y = x+1$, determine the coefficient of $y^2$

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, contest-math

I saw another post with the same problem but it didn't really answer my question.

This problem is [Problem 11](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1986_AIME_Problems/Problem_11) from AIME 1986:

> The polynomial $$1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+x^{16}-x^{17}$$ may be written in the form $$a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+\cdots+a_{16}y^{16}+a_{17}y^{17}$$ where $y=x+1$ and the $a_i$ are constants. Find $a_2$.

Here's my attempt:

Starting from $1-x + x^2 + ... -x^{17} = a_0 + a_1y + ... +a_{17}y^{17}$, let $x = -1$:

$$ 1 + 1 + 1 + \dotsb + 1 = a_0 + a_1\cdot 0 + \dotsb + a_{17}\cdot 0.$$

Hence, $18 = a_0$.

Letting  $x = 9$:

$$1 - 9 + 9^2 +\dotsb - 9^{17} =  18 + a_1\cdot 10 + \dotsb +a_{17}\cdot 10^{17}.$$

The LHS is a geometric sequence with $r = -9$

$$-15,009,463,529,699,912 = 18 + a_1\cdot 10 + \dotsb +a_{17}\cdot 10^{17}.$$

Hence, $a_2 = -9$.

However, this isn't the answer and I don't understand why. I feel like I must be making a stupid mistake somewhere but I cannot find it...

Comment: Where did you conclude $a_2 = -9$ from?

Comment: From the hundred's place. @Azlif  To OP: you seem to be assuming that $a_1 < 10$, where do you demonstrate this fact?

Comment: It's nice to have the question in the question....

Comment: @Azlif The hundreds digits on the LHS is equal to 9. By the same logic, $a_{17} = -1$ (which is correct) and $a_{16} = -5$ which I am almost certain is incorrect!

Comment: I guess differentiating twice and then putting $x=-1$ should help. I think you may have thought this, but still.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I thought it followed that $a_1 = -3$ from the penultimate equation... Am I being incredibly dim?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Could you please explain why the approach is flawed? Thanks

Comment: @Tony Wow, thanks for the tip. I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @220284 As OmnipotentEntity explained, you are implicitly assuming each $a_i$ lies in $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. That's not true.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah I see now. Thank you for the explanation (and the solution).

Comment: You say that there is another post which addresses this question.  Can you please link to that post, and explain how the answers there don't address your concerns?

Comment: If you add $15\times 10^{15}$ to both sides then the LHS is a positive integer whose hundreds-digit is $0$. But this will still not help to find $a_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method has *some* merit, but fails with too big coefficients. For example
$$ (10+1)^4=11^4=14641$$
corresponds nicely with
$$ (x+1)^4=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1,$$
but $11^5=161051$ does *not* imply that 
$$ (x+1)^5=x^6+6x^4+x^3+5x+1$$
instead of correctly
$$ (x+1)^5=x^6+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+5x+1.$$
You could find $a_1$ by manipulating the polynomial such that it becomes the constant term and then plugging in $y=0$ again.
Namely, for $y\ne0$ (equivalently, $x\ne -1$), we have
$$\begin{align}a_1+a_2y+a_3y^3+\cdots a_{17}y^{16}
&=\frac{(a_0+a_1y+\cdots+a_{17}y^{17})-a_0}{y}\\
&=\frac{(1-x+x^2\mp\cdots -x^{17})-18}{x+1}\\
&=\frac{(x+1)(-x^{16}+2x^{15}-3x^{14}\pm\cdots+16x-17)}{x+1}\\
&=-x^{16}+2x^{15}-3x^{14}\pm\cdots+16x-17
\end{align} $$
The first and least expression are also equal when $y=0$ / $x=-1$ and by pluggin in, you obtain
$$a_1=-1-2-3-\cdots -17. $$

You might repeat the method to find $a_2$. But actually, you could, perhaps more simply, perform a polynomial division
of $1-x\pm\cdots -x^{17}$ by $x^3+3x^2+3x+1$ ($=(x+1)^3$) right away and have a look and the quadratic polynomial that you obtain as remainder!

Comment: After 'instead of correctly' do you mean $x^5$ as the first term? Or you've completely lost me. Thanks for the useful example though. I feel like this was the most useful answer in terms of why my approach was invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=1-x+x^2-\cdots-x^{17}$. This is a GP:
$$f(x)=\frac{1-x^{18}}{1+x}.$$
If we set $x=y-1$ we get
$$f(x)=\frac{1-(y-1)^{18}}{y}.$$
This can be expanded by the binomial theorem:
$$f(x)=\frac1y\left(18y-\binom{18}2y^2+\binom{18}3y^3-\cdots-y^{18}\right)$$
from which you can read off the $a_j$.

Comment: The question here proposes a particular solution to the problem, then asks where they went wrong.  You have provided a different solution to the problem, but have not addressed the asker's concern about why their method fails.  As such, I do not believe that this post answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $0\leq a_i<10$ for all $i$. One may observe that the polynomial may be written as $\sum_{n=0}^{n=17} (1-y)^n$, so the coefficient $a_i$ of $y^i$ is equal to the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{j=17} (-1)^i\binom{j}{i}=(-1)^i\binom{18}{i+1}$, most of which are not between 0 and 10.